# Google Drive V3 Api get File Name, C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

How do I get a single files name from a get request using the drive api?

I have made a request but there is not metadata about the file there, I can only download it.

```
var fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
```

Apparently this return a files.get in the response according to this [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#request)

I just want to download a file and have its name displayed, not just its id

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063691/how-to-get-file-name-and-real-path-of-google-drive-document

Answer (score 4):

For Google Drive V3:

C#:
`string f = driveService.Files.Get(fileId).Execute().Name;`

VB:
`Dim f As String = driveService.Files.Get(fileId).Execute().Name`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the file name from the `Title` property in the `File` class:

```
string FileName = service.Files.Get(FileId).Execute().Title;
```

and for downloading,

```
// DriveService _service: a valid Authendicated DriveService
// Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File _fileResource: Resource of the file to download. (from service.Files.Get(FileId).Execute();)  
// string _saveTo: Full file path to save the file

public static void downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
    {
        try
        {
            var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl);
            byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    /// 
    /// Download a file
    /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
    /// 
    /// a Valid authenticated DriveService
    /// File resource of the file to download
    /// location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.
    /// 
    public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
        {
            try
            {
                var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl );
                byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
                return true;                  
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code ripped from my [Google drive api C# download](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-download/) tutorial. Which I haven't updated in ages so if there are any issues let me know and I will fix them.

Comment: Is it okay to mix V3 API calls with V2 api calls?

Comment: Not really ideal I will try to find some v3 code it should be very similar to v2. Sorry about my lax in reading I keep forgetting about the new api