# How to get file path of google drive document in Android

Tags: android, file, google-drive-api

I am trying to access file from device. All works goods but when i browse and select file from google drive it gives null path. I have seen many question but didn't got the answer. One solution which i got below only gives me the file name.

```
  public static String getGDriveDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                         String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_display_name";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Is it possible to get that file? Because that file is on the drive and not on the device. Please help me how can i get that file.

Comment: If the file is on google drive, on the internet, then there is no path to it. But you got the uri to it. So now you can open an input stream on the uri and read the content of the file.

Comment: Yes file is on the google drive. So using input stream is the only the one way to read that file

Comment: Yes. But every file is read using an input stream. Nothing new. So what do you have in mind?

Comment: This seems similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063691/how-to-get-file-name-and-real-path-of-google-drive-document).

Comment: @FaisalAhmed : you got solution for this? I got input stream after that what to do?Anyone knows?

Comment: Did you guys find anything?

Comment: @ShubhamAnand , I am not sure. If you find any solution please post it below so that it can be helpful to others.

Comment: @FaisalAhmed This question was asked 4 years ago by you. You would have figured out anything to get the solution.